# KineticJS, Paint like program, brush gaps

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to do something like paint with KineticJS. I am trying to draw the color with circles that originate from the mouse position. However the eventlistener of the mouse position seems too slow and when I move the mouse too fast the circles drawn are far from each other resulting this:

I have seen people filling array with points drawing lines between them, but I thought thats very bad for optimization because after dubbing the screen too much the canvas starts lagging because it has too much lines that it redraws every frame. I decided to cancel the cleaning of the layer and I am adding new circle at the current mouse position and I remove the old one for optimization. However since Im not drawing lines on fast mouse movement it leaves huge gaps. I would be very grateful if anyone can help me with this.

Here is my code:

```js
(function() {
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'main-drawing-window',
      width: 920,
      height: 750
    }),
    workplace = document.getElementById('main-drawing-window'),
    layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
      clearBeforeDraw: false
    }),
    border = new Kinetic.Rect({
      stroke: "black",
      strokeWidth: 2,
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      width: stage.getWidth(),
      height: stage.getHeight()
    }),
    brush = new Kinetic.Circle({
      radius: 20,
      fill: 'red',
      strokeWidth: 2,
      x: 100,
      y: 300
    });

  Input = function() {
    this.mouseIsDown = false;
    this.mouseX = 0;
    this.mouseY = 0;
    this.offsetX = 0;
    this.offsetY = 0;
  };

  var input = new Input();

  document.documentElement.onmousedown = function(ev) {
    input.mouseIsDown = true;
  };

  document.documentElement.onmouseup = function(ev) {
    input.mouseIsDown = false;
  };

  document.documentElement.onmousemove = function(ev) {
    ev = ev || window.event;

    // input.mouseX = (ev.clientX - workplace.offsetLeft);
    // input.mouseY = (ev.clientY - workplace.offsetTop);
    input.mouseX = (ev.offsetX);
    input.mouseY = (ev.offsetY);
  };

  function DistanceBetweenPoints(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    return Math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)));
  }

  var canvasDraw = setInterval(function() {
    // console.log(input);
    if (input.mouseIsDown) {
      workplace.style.cursor = "crosshair";
      var currentBrushPosition = brush.clone();
      currentBrushPosition.setX(input.mouseX);
      currentBrushPosition.setY(input.mouseY);
      // var distance = DistanceBetweenPoints(brush.getX(), brush.getY(), currentBrushPosition.getX(), currentBrushPosition.getY());
      // if (distance > brush.getRadius() * 2) {
      //     var fillingLine = new Kinetic.Line({
      //         points: [brush.getX(), brush.getY(), currentBrushPosition.getX(), currentBrushPosition.getY()],
      //         stroke: 'yellow',
      //         strokeWidth: brush.getRadius()*2,
      //         lineJoin: 'round'
      //     });
      //     // layer.add(fillingLine);
      // }

      layer.add(currentBrushPosition);
      brush.remove();
      brush = currentBrushPosition;
      layer.draw();
      // if (fillingLine) {
      //     fillingLine.remove();
      // }
    }
    if (!input.mouseIsDown) {
      workplace.style.cursor = 'default';
    }
  }, 16);

  layer.add(border);
  stage.add(layer);
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Coloring Game</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/kineticjs/5.2.0/kinetic.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="main-drawing-window"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./JS files/canvas-draw.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use individual `Kinetic.Circle`s for each mousemove. Every Kinetic object is a "managed" object and that management takes up a lot of resources. KineticJS will slow to a crawl as the number of circles increases with every mousemove.

Instead, use a `Kinetic.Shape` and draw you circles onto the canvas with

```
// This is Pseudo-code since I haven't worked with KineticJS in a while
shapeContext.beginPath();
shapeContext.arc(mouseX,mouseY,20,0,Math.PI*2);
shapeContext.fillStrokeShape(this);
```

This will probably clear your problem, but if the mouse is moved very far in a single mousemove then you might have to draw a `lineTo` (instead of `arc`) between the last mouse point and the current far-away mouse point.